# Scikit-learn - how to use single static validation set for CV object?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, scikit-optimize

In Scikit-learn `RandomSearchCV` and `GridSearchCV` require the cross validation object for the `cv` argument, e.g. `GroupKFold` or any other CV splitter from `sklearn.model_selection`.

However, how can I use single, **static** validation set? I have very large training set, large validation set and I only need the interface of CV objects, not whole cross validation.

Specifically, I'm using Scikit-optimize and `BayesSearchCV` ([docs](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html)) and it requires the CV object (same interface as regular Scikit-learn `SearchCV` objects). I want to use my chosen validation set with it, not whole CV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs of the model selection objects of `scikit-learn`, e.g. [`GridSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), are maybe a bit clearer how to achieve this:

> cv: int, cross-validation generator or an iterable, default=None
>
> - ...
> - **An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices**.

So you need the arrays of indices for training and test samples as a tuple and then wrap them in an iterable, e.g. a list:

```py
train_indices = [...]  # indices for training
test_indices = [...]  # indices for testing

cv = [(train_indices, test_indices)]
```

Pass this `cv` defined with a single tuple to the model selection object and it will always use the same samples for training and testing.